# 3D randomized generation of planets

Tags: algorithm, procedural-generation

For a project, I'm doing creation of planets in 3D space, based around a center "homeworld", that are randomly generated in all directions from the origin.

I've looked at procedural generation and Perlin noise, but I couldn't find a decent way to make them applicable, but I'm new to randomized generation of any kind.

Any good starting points for an algorithm for 3D-point generation, centered around the origin, preferably based on a seed (so the same seed makes the same universe).

Thanks!

Comment: All planets of a star system (usually) orbit around the center of mass (star) at a common plane or with small deviation (angle) from such a plane.

Comment: Sadly, we're not going for realism. It's just going to be a practically endless expanse of planets that increase in size the further away you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a set of different random numbers rather than trying for a specific algorithm to do this with a single seed.

```
first one is 1-360 is the rotation around the y axis
second one is 1-180 is the deviation from the y axis (wobble)
third one is 1-<really big  number> is the distance from your centre point (homeworld)
fourth (optional) one is to randomize the radius of the planet
fifth (optional) is to randomize the colour of the object
```

To plot your planet then it's just some simple trigonometry to work out the location in 3d space (x,y,z) from your origin (homeworld).

And so long as your seed values for each are the same you will be able to generate a very large planet space.

If you want to do this with a single seed, then use that seed to generate 'random' seed numbers for all the subsequent random number generators.

Comment: The only thing I'm not clear on is how I make it generate a certain "density" of planets? Perhaps just adding a number I can adjust that creates "cushion" between them or something?

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea in the long time it took to load this page which I don't see represented yet.

You could start with a tetrahedron and then, for a specified number of iterations,

- select a triangular face at random

  - replace the face with a new tetrahedron erected on that base.

With a completely uniform random number distribution, this should approximate a sphere. With a deterministic PRNG, the result should be reproducible by using the same initial seed.